# Restaurant Galaxy schema

Tags: database-theory, data-mining

I want to make a Galaxy schema of a Restaurant. There are 2 fact tables sales and purchases. sales are related to customer and purchases to supplier of ingredients.
Now my question is how can i make galaxy schema
and from where i can find large dataset for my dataware house project

Comment: Have you tried checking your lecture notes, asking friends and TAs? What do you not understand specifically?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Requests for datasets are probably off-topic here.